# Filling boostrap cards with data from a mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4, card

I am trying to fill bootstrap cards with data from a database.
I am very close.
I have the mainphp file called project.php

A file with a function called component to fill them, called component.php.

And a connectDB.php file, that connect the DB and extracts the information from a table.

I am aware this is alot of code so I highlighted 2 areas the problem is definitely in...Apologies if too much, I can remove the function if necessary as it works..

here is an extract from project.php

```
<?php
require_once('connect/connectDB.php');
require_once('component.php');




?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

   <title>The Wild Music Shop</title>
   
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!--Font awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- i have no idea why it won't link -->
    <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="myCSS/somecss.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myCSS/somecss.css">

</head>
<body>

    <!-- the cards -->
    <div class = "container" id="thecards">
        <div class = "row text-center py-5">

//Definite problem here
             <?php
             $result = getData();
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                 component($row['InstName'], $row['Price'], $row['ProductImg'], $row['description']);
             }
            ?>  
            

        </div>

    </div>
</html>
```

This component definitely works as I tested it

```
<?php

function component($pInstName, $pPrice, $pProductImg, $pdescription){
    $element = "
    
    <div class=\"col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3 my-md-0\">
                <form action=\"index.php\" method=\"post\">
                    <div class=\"card shadow\">
                        <div>
                            <img src=\ $pProductImg\" alt=\"Image1\" class=\"img-fluid card-img-top\">
                        </div>
                        <div class=\"card-body\">
                            <h5 class=\"card-title\">Our $pInstName</h5>
                            <h6>
                                <i class=\"fas fa-star\"></i>
                                <i class=\"fas fa-star\"></i>
                                <i class=\"fas fa-star\"></i>
                                <i class=\"fas fa-star\"></i>
                                <i class=\"far fa-star\"></i>
                            </h6>
                            <p class=\"card-text\">
                            $pdescription
                            </p>
                            <h5>
                               
                                <span class=\"price\">$$pPrice</span>
                            </h5>
                            <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-warning my-3\" name=\"add\">Add to Cart </button>
                             
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    ";
    echo $element;
}
?>
```

and finally here is the connectDB.php

```
<?php


        //Create a database connection
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbuser = "root";
        $dbpassword = "";
        $dbname = "g00398295";

        $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname);
        
        //Test if connection occoured
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            die("DB connection failed: " .
                mysqli_connect_error() .
                    " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
                    );
        }

        if (!$connection)
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
            
            $sql = "select * from Instruments where itemno = 1; ";
            
            $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            
            echo "Pls work".$row['InstName'];
            
            mysqli_close($connection);
            //get product from Database
//Definite problem here
        function getData(){
            $sql = "select * from $this->tablename";

            $result = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                return $result;
            }

        }

?>
```

I am awar the problem is somewhere in the connection step. I am very new to php in general and have been at this very long, I would appreciate help!

Comment: You really need to narrow down the issue. What is the exact issue you are having? Are you receiving any errors? Does it just not format like you expect?

Comment: yes sorry i had multiple errors as I was tweaking code constantly. I am very tired. I kknow slack is not about getting people to write code i just knew I was very close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function `getData()` that has `"$this->table"`. Dont copy paste the codes without understanding what it does.

Clean up your `connectDB.php`:

```
<?php
    //Create a database connection
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbuser     = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $dbname     = "g00398295";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);
        
    //Test if connection occoured
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die("DB connection failed: " .
            mysqli_connect_error() .
            " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
    }
?>
```

In `project.php`:

```
<div class = "row text-center py-5">
    //Definite problem here
    <?php
        $sql = "select * from Instruments where itemno = 1; ";
 
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            component($row['InstName'], $row['Price'], $row['ProductImg'], $row['description']);
        }
    ?>  
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying to end the php script there? When I did not do that I got a can't pass sql connection error. Then I did that and I got one item in the list through

Comment: Ok After some tweaking, you have solved my issue in a very simple way. thank you!